# Plotting multiple time series from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe loaded from file in the following format:

```
ID,Date,Time,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
0063,04/21/2020,11:22:55,0.0347,0.41,1440,10.5
0064,04/21/2020,11:22:56,0.0355,0.41,1440,10.4
...
9849,04/22/2020,10:46:19,0.058,1.05,1460,10.6
```

I have tried multiple methods of plotting a line graph of each value vs date/time or a single graph with multiple subplots with limited success. I am hoping someone with much more experience may have an elegant solution to try as opposed to my blind swinging. Note that the dataset may have large breaks in time between days. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

parsing dates during the import of the pandas dataframe seemed to be my biggest issue. Once I added parse_dates to the pd.read_csv I was able to define the dt column and plot with matplotlib as expected.

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_text, parse_dates = [["Date", "Time"]])

dt = df["Date_Time"]
```